# How to deploy multiple logic app with single arm template via Azure Devops CI/CD?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-logic-apps, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have multiple logic app with corresponding ARM template. Now, I want to merge different ARM templates into one ARM template and deploy the multiple logic app at the same time via AZURE-DEVOPS pipeline.

Comment: Ideally I would caution you against it, keep them separated  and follow single  responsibility  principle

Comment: May I know what's the status of this? Does below suggestion is help to you? Free to comment if you still has any puzzle to it:-)

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Thanks for your help. I am still trying to implement your suggestion,  by using "template link " property.

It would be great , if you can  please give me some examples of working ARM templates by using nested template approach

Comment: I have just been through something similar.  I have collection of related Logic Apps and connectors in a Resource Group and export Template before editing it into single template file and parameter.test.json / parameter.prod.json template files.  These are added to GitHub.

In DevOps I have created a Release Pipeline whose Artifect is the GitHub repo, each stage item then has a job ARM deploy, where I reference the artifact and set the main template file and relevant parameter file in the relevant placeholders.

Comment: @drewglew 

Can you please give an example of how to call child template from storage account ?

I have uploaded one arm-template into storage account and I want to link it into master arm template ?

Comment: I am unsure when using a storage account as authentication is not trivial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-tutorial-linked-template?tabs=azure-powershell was a great intro for me in setting up inside GitHub.. I did have a problem referencing private GitHub repository, but managed to get this working in the end.

Answer (score 2):

For your scenario, you need firstly make change to your ARM template structure.

For example, I want to combine 4 ARM templates into one ARM template. So that I can just use one `ARM template deploy` task to deploy 4 services.

Now, I need create a combined ARM templates file with below structure:

```
   Repo ArmDeploy
    |    Nested Templates
    |    |    NestOne
    |    |       |   NestOne.json
    |    |       |   NestOne.parameters.json
    |    |    NestTwo
    |    |       |   NestTwo.json
    |    |       |   NestTwo.parameters.json
    |    |    NestThree
    |    |       |   NestThree.json
    |    |       |   NestThree.parameters.json
    |    |    NestFour
    |    |       |   NestFour.json
    |    |       |   NestFour.parameters.json
    |    azuredeploy.json
    |    azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

For the contents of `azuredeploy.yml` and `azuredeploy.parameters.yml`, you can check the sample and the description from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/deploy-nested-template-environments), along with this [one](https://dzone.com/articles/nested-arm-templates-modularity-and-reuse).

---

Now, it is available to use only one `ARM deploy` task to deploy several services. Just specify azuredeploy.json and to the task parameter:

```
- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
  displayName: 'Several services deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxxxx'
    resourceGroupName: 'xxxx'
    location: 'xxxxxx'
    csmFile: azuredeploy.json
    csmParametersFile: azuredeploy.parameters.json
```