# How to deploy multiple ARM with Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Ì would like to deploy Storage, SQL Logical Server and SQL database with ARM. Currently templates are all located under own folder in repo /Storage /SQLLogicalServer /SQLDB

I can deploy they one by one with dedicated pipeline currently.

What is best practice to deploy several Azure resources with single pipeline?
Is it good idea to use one master ARM template that call each resource ARM?
Any tutorial or article about this scenario?

Comment: Hi Kenny, is there any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is best practice to deploy several Azure resources with single
>   pipeline? Is it good idea to use one master ARM template that call
>   each resource ARM? Any tutorial or article about this scenario?

You can follow [Deploy nested Azure Resource Manager templates for testing environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/deploy-nested-template-environments) to combine your three templates into one, then you would easily use one single pipeline to deploy them together. Here's a [similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61118762/10910450) like yours.

**Note:**

If you have separate pipelines for your three ARM templates, you can easily customize them. E.g: You can set the pipeline to be triggered only when the corresponding ARM template repo is changed. If the ARM templates are in one pipeline, they would be deployed even when only one of them is changed. (In that scenario, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61133851/10910450) as workaround.)

Whether it's good idea totally depends on your needs/scenarios. Hope it helps :)